# Rust equivalent of GCHandle.Alloc

Tags: c#, memory, rust

What is the equivalent of this code in Rust?

```cs
byte[] bytes = [...]; // some given bytes
bytesInt = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
bytesIntPtr = bytesInt.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

In Rust the resulting pointer should be of type `*const c_void` and the input is `bytes: Vec<u8>`.
I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You need to use Marshal : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshalling and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc?view=net-6.0

Comment: I edited the question because it was not clear enough

Comment: It is in the second link.  A PTR is 32 bits which is an address.  The PTR is an array of bytes (u8).  Yu need Rust 1.64.1.  See : https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/09/22/Rust-1.64.0.html

Comment: Do you just want a pointer to the internal buffer? `bytes.as_ptr()` returns a `*const u8` which you can cast if you need to.

Comment: Please add the rust code you have to your question.

Comment: I did some tests, there was some other code that was causing the issue. bytes.as_ptr() as working fine.
Put your answer so I mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pointer to the vector's internal buffer, you can use [as_ptr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_ptr) e.g.

```
let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
let p: *const u8 = v.as_ptr();
```